# react native non-state global variable

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using react native + redux patten

What is the proper way of storing a global non-state data.

This data gets updated very frequently, and I want them to access/modify by redux actions, and I don't want data update to trigger any UI updates.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use just a standard JavaScript variable? If you don't want UI updates  why not just avoid the react infrastructure altogether?

Comment: What kind of data are you storing?